# What is an adjective to describe a person who watches a lot of porn?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Sorry not a native speaker. Trying to translate a word to English.

Like in a situation where you walk in on your brother and his friends watching porn.

You yell: 'You _________ kids!

Preferably in the derogatory or pejorative sense.

I thought horny was the word but both definition in Wiktionary does not apply.

Comment: [Pornoholic](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pornoholic) would be an informal term that most everyone would understand.

Comment: What is the word in the language you're translating from?

Comment: I have to ask: does this happen a lot?

Comment: *horny* probably works better than you think vis-a-vis the wiktionary definition.  It's got a connotation of sex-starved as much as actively aroused.  Vocabulary.com calls it "great sexual desire" not physical arousal.  Don't make the mistake of thinking it means "having a boner."

Comment: teenager seems to fit

Comment: "male" seems to fit :-P

Comment: Define: "a lot"...

Comment: Informally, I would use *porn hound*.

Comment: You sex-starved degenerates should get a life.

Comment: To take it up a notch on the pejorative part, you could say, "You socially inept, interpersonally incompetent, sex-starved degenerates might have more success if you got out more and actually tried talking to some live women."  OK, so that's taking it up two notches.

Comment: Having given a serious answer below, I feel the need to comment that the most _appropriate_ adjective for a person (especially a teenager or similar age) who watches a lot of porn, is surely, **_average_** ;-)

Answer (score 30):

In colloquial British:
You perverts; **you pervs**; you pervy kids.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pervert

> n. (pûr′vûrt′)
>
> A person whose sexual practices or interests are considered abnormal or deviant.

Comment: **Perv**ect short and supported answer.

Comment: "You **Perverted** kids." fits the example best.

Comment: @MD-Tech I disagree, if kids is required (to further belittle) I would go for pervy (as I wrote) but as a British speaker I would recommend "you pervs" for the scenario described. "You perverted kids" is a bit of a mouthful for a mortified exclamation.

Comment: "pervy" fits the tone of the original question better IMHO.  "You perverted kids" sounds like moralizing, while "You pervy kids" is more of a colloquial joshing.  I guess it depends on what you're trying to convey.

Comment: Am I the only person not seeing how "watching a lot of porn" is related to having abnormal/deviant sexual practices or interests"? Especially if we're talking about teenagers.

Comment: Regardless of whether watching porn in a group is normal activity, it isn't socially acceptable. ; imparting shame is how we police social norms..

Answer (score 14):

Lecherous.

From Google:
adjective: lecherous
having or showing excessive or offensive sexual desire.
"she ignored his lecherous gaze"

Comment: I think this is the best term. We don't know whether they are addicted, or whether the OP thinks it's perverted. The OP just wants to voice a sense of "too much", or "inappropriate". The word for that is *lecherous* (as I learned from [Douthat's -- well -- not eulogy, but kakology to  Hugh Hefner in the New York Times.](https://nyti.ms/2fFUzbs) )

Answer (score 11):

You sleazy kids!

My concise Oxford dictionary is too old to be useful for current slang meanings, but a Google tells me that the Cambridge dictionary [defines *sleazy* as](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sleazy):

> sleazy
>   adjective UK ​ /ˈsliː.zi/ US ​ /ˈsliː.zi/
> ​
>   dirty, cheap, or not socially acceptable, especially relating to moral or sexual matters:

Answer (score 5):

Pornomaniac

I'm not native but i got the sense of combining words together to give you a better meaning
I think this is the word you need

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a neutral term, [**"pornography addicted"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornography_addiction) will fit.

If, on the other hand, you disapprove of that behavior and want to show your disapproval, you might say they have **"dirty minds".** (Hey, you guys have dirty minds)

> - [**dirty**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dirty) (adj)  a. obscene or indecent: dirty movies; a dirty joke.
>     b. Lewd or lecherous: a dirty mind.

Comment: Using the adjective "dirty" with kids is usually referring to their state of cleanliness. On the other hand, a "dirty old man" usually refers to that person's mind and behaviour.

Comment: Albeit the context in the question is very clear, I'd opt for "disgusting kids"  or "deviants", there's less likelihood of the reader misinterpreting

Comment: @Mari-LouA Or maybe they could just be allowed to be normal teenagers and watch their porn...

Comment: @Cerberus I'm commenting on the term "dirty" not whether it is right or wrong for teenagers to watch porn. And if that was meant to be a joke, sorry. But ambiguity is rife on SE.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I think words like "disgusting" and "deviant" are rather strong terms to call a child.

Comment: @Cerberus it is the OP who is looking for a derogatory and pejorative term, not I. And who says it is a child, it could be 16-year-olds for all we know. And, frankly, there's some really bad stuff out there, so it all depends.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Glad we got that cleared up, then.

Answer (score 4):

If someone watches a lot of porn, they are likely a very **libidinous** person.

From *Oxford English Dictionary*:

> [*adjective*] Of persons, their lives, actions, desires: Given to, full of, or characterized by lust or lewdness; lustful, lecherous, lewd.

The word shares a root with **libido**, which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libido) describes bluntly as another word for *sex drive*.

The word is less pejorative than other words available in a thesaurus.

**Lustful** is often used more pejoratively, likely because of its common use in reference to the Bible where "lust" describes earthly, sinful desires.

Answer (score 2):

**perverse**

Derived from the noun perversion.

> **Perversion** is a type of human behavior that deviates from that which
>   is understood to be orthodox or normal. Although the term perversion
>   can refer to a variety of forms of deviation, it is most often used to
>   describe sexual behaviors that are considered particularly abnormal,
>   repulsive or obsessive.

Comment: *Perverted* was the first word that came to my mind. [*Perverse*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perverse) is a good fit but I usually think of it in MW's second sense, "obstinate in opposing what is right, reasonable, or accepted". Perhaps this is a peculiarly Australian usage.

Answer (score 2):

**porn addicted**

It is neutral and describe the situation avoiding to emit a judgement

Comment: The OP would like to state a judgement though: "derogatory or pejorative." Also, I've never heard "emit" used with "judgement," is that typical to some regions?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: Possibly a literal translation from French : `émettre un jugement`.

Answer (score 1):

How about *porny*?

Merriam-Webster defines it as "related to porn".

Comment: I do like *porny* for its rhyming with *horny*.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a common everyday word for this. Most of the suggestions are very uncommon words that wouldn't really be used by people.

In reality the exclamation would be more general and different, such as "You disgusting kids!" or "You sick bastards!". Perhaps just a one word comment - "Disgusting!"

(Reply to comments:  @terdon - yes it would, but disgust rather than neutrality or admiration is explicitly implied/requested in the question. @Peter Schneider - like many expressions it  depends who says it and in what tone (imagine "that's *evil*" said to a teenager by a judge or a friend of theirs))

Comment: "Sick" can also communicate a sense of admiration, like "Wow, that's *sick*!" I'd like to use it in this sense.

Comment: Calling a teenager caught watching porn a "sick bastard" would say more about you than about the kid.

Answer (score 0):

"You **[voyeuristic](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Exhibitionism_and_voyeurism)** kids" seems an apt choice.

> Voyeurism means that a person likes looking at the sexual parts of
>   other people or likes to watch other people doing sexual things while
>   whoever the voyeur is watching is unaware.

The only aspect of the term that might not fit your request, is the inherent desire of the voyeur to be covert, from the perspective of the exhibitionist.